# Elasticsearch sliced scroll after count not working

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, count

I have a weird problem...

Well, from the beginning...

Elasticsearch version 6.8

I run a sliced scroll in parallel (using python elasticsearch-dsl library and python multiprocessing Pool), which works ok. Code more or less looks like this:

```
def dump_slice(slice_no, search, slices):
    search = search.extra(slice={'id': slice_no, 'max': slices})
    return [hit for hit in search.scan()]

...

search = ... # elasticsearch-dsl Search object
pool = Pool(10)

dump_slice_partial = partial(dump_slice, search=search, slices=10)
results = list(chain(*pool.map(dump_slice_partial, range(query_threads))))

pool.close()
```

but when I add run some `count` before (any - even not `count` on the search object that I'm using in sliced scroll) it doesn't work - elasticsearch throws 500/400/timeouts (randomly)

code looks like this

```
def dump_slice(slice_no, search, slices):
    search = search.extra(slice={'id': slice_no, 'max': slices})
    return [hit for hit in search.scan()]

...

search = ... # elasticsearch-dsl Search object
total = search.count()
pool = Pool(10)

dump_slice_partial = partial(dump_slice, search=search, slices=10)
results = list(chain(*pool.map(dump_slice_partial, range(query_threads))))

pool.close()
```

[the only thing I added here is `total = search.count()`]

in this example during `scan()` it gives me:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)')
```

or

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Failed to parse request body')
```

or some randomly 500 or timeout.

It doesn't make sense to me, looks like some bug in ES...

Has anyone seen this before?

How I could get the total number of results before calling sliced scroll in parallel?